# Popup not showing in Chrome Extension, but firing all events when clicking icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been struggling with this issue since yesterday and I have run out of ideas to figure out what is going on.

I am developing a Chrome extension with a popup menu with a few buttons to fire certain events. The problem is that instead of showing the popup.html when clicking the icon extension, it just fires all associated events with the buttons.

My original extension had a persistent background script, so when I was debuggin it, the error that showed up was "cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null". I have already looked it up and, apparently, it had to do with the position of the `script src` line inside the popup.html file. I tried relocating it but nothing changed.

After trying many alternatives to do the same in other ways and comparing my code with other sample extensions, I created a very simple extension to demonstrate the trouble I am dealing with. It's just a three-buttons popup and when you click each button, a message should appear showing some text. The files are:

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="OpenButton">Open</button>
    <button id="StartButton">Start</button>
    <button id="StopButton">Stop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function open(){alert("open");}
function start(){alert("start");}
function stop(){alert("stop");}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('OpenButton').addEventListener(
      'click', open());
  document.getElementById('StartButton').addEventListener(
      'click', start());
  document.getElementById('StopButton').addEventListener(
      'click', stop());
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that displays a message",
  "description": "Display a message",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Display this message.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Basically, I took a sample extension (it offered a popup with 4 buttons to change the background colour of the current page) and edited it. This extension worked fine, but in this new extension I made, when you click the extension icon, all three messages are displayed, one after another and no popup shows up.

I can't see where the conflict is and I couldn't find any question with the same issue. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening an `alert()` causes the popup window to lose focus.

Which, in turn, immediately closes it.

Don't use `alert()` in the popup - to debug, use `console.log()`, the output of which is accessible if you right-click your extension's browser action and select "Inspect popup".

Comment: Good point. That explains why the popup never gets to be visible. 
Eventhough the buttons were now visible, they wouldn't fire any event. But finally I realised what the problem was: I am not passing the function, just firing it! TT_TT

In fact I didn't even realise by my self, I found someone with a similar problem. I was adding `()` when I passed the functions (i.e. `addEventListener('click', open());`). I thought it would make no difference, but it certainly does.

Well, thank you for your reply. I think this will solve the problem with my original extension

Comment: Note that it sometimes makes sense to do this (execute a function when assigning a listener) - that function may itself return a (customized) listener function. [Higher-order functions](http://www.sitepoint.com/higher-order-functions-javascript/) are a nice feature of JS!

Comment: Nice but tricky for newbies! Anyway,  I'll keep this in mind, it can be handy in the future. Thanks!